# How to store multiple values in a SQL Server variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to store values from a SELECT statement into a variable which is capable of holding more than one value because my SELECT statement returns multiple values of type INT. This is how my SP looks like so far.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "ESG"."SP_ADD"
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Id table(identifiers VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO @Id (identifiers) VALUES('axaa1aaa-aaaa-a5aa-aaaa-aa8aaaa9aaaa');
INSERT INTO @Id (identifiers) VALUES('bxbb1bbb-bbbb-b5bb-bbb4-bb8bbbb9bbbf');

DECLARE @tranID INT = (SELECT 
DOCUMENT_SET_.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID 
                            FROM DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION 
                                    WHERE DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION.IDENTIFIER IN (SELECT identifiers FROM @Id));  

END
```

Variable @tranID should be a list or an array to hold the ids. Is it possible to do it SQL Server?

Comment: Why don't you declare it as Table? `DECLARE @tranID TABLE (IDs INT);`, then insert your data, `INSERT INTO  @tranID SELECT ID FROM ....`

Comment: It complaints for `Incorrect syntax near '='.` if I declare it as a table

Comment: Because you INSERT into a table. You don't SET it with =

Comment: What are you going to do with `@tranID` from there?  Just return it to the client?  If so just do a `SELECT` and don't "return" a value.

Comment: Actually once I got the ids I will loop through and I have to do some ore operations. First I need to get the ids

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare a variable of type `table`

```
DECLARE @tblTrans TABLE (
    tranID INT
);

INSERT INTO @tblTrans 
SELECT DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID 
FROM ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION 
WHERE DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION.IDENTIFIER 
    IN (SELECT identifiers FROM @envelopeId);
```

Depending on what you want to do with the values after this, you could declare a cursor to loop through them or select straight from the variable.

You could also look into using a temporary table depending on what scope you need.

Comment: Looks like it is working but how can I make sure that @tranId has the values.

Comment: @David You may need to declare the size of the INT column if it's saying the data would be truncated. I think the default is 4 places so just increase the number depending on what the size of the column you select from is.

To check the values are correct, you can just `SELECT * FROM @tblTrans` in SSMS at the end of the procedure, it should print the results to the output window.

Comment: Awesome. I've increased the size. Thanks sRoyal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, only take the firs row of example. Do u try this?

```
select DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID,
(STUFF((SELECT '-' + convert(varchar(max),DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID) 
         FROM  ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION  
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS example
FROM ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION
```

Comment: convert the values for xml and then take everthing into a string concated with "-". that what you want to achieve?